# scraping webpage data modification

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

its just that i have come up with some code, which does the copy paste webpage into text format in my excel sheet.

few modification were required.
Addition modification requires to make a loop through code so that it access the input from Excel(in attachment-Input sheet) and make changes to URL(i noticed in URL that only last word needs to be changed which will be taken from excel file column 1and so on till its find blank).

As, its looping correctly but there is no loop for data pasting henece its dumping all the looped data to one cell.

My basic requirment of this macro is to access link from column A, and paste its data to column B.

```js
Sub Trial()
    Dim IE As Object
Dim URL As Range

For Each URL In Range("A1:A3").Cells
 
    Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    With IE
        .Visible = True
        
    
    
        .navigate "1ox11is" & URL
        Do Until .readyState = 4: DoEvents: Loop
        
       

            'Range("B1").Value = .document.body.innerText
            'wsSheet.Range("B" & Rows).Value = .document.body.innerText
            Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B1").Value = .document.body.innerText

            .Quit
            
        End With
Next

 
End Sub
```

Comment: What does this have to do with PHP? And what is the actual question?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that links are in cells A1,A2,A3 etc. and data from websites is supposed to appear next to them in cells B1,B2,B3 etc, change:

```
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B1").Value = .document.body.innerText
```

to:

```
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B" & URL.Row).Value = .document.body.innerText
```